# jQuery: issue with each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, each

I am new to jQuery and hope someone here can help me with this:

**Basically what I am trying to do is the following:**

1. Check for all elements with the class "`limit`" and get their `maxlength`.
2. Find an element with the class "`count`" in the same row.
3. Add the found maxlength to the count element's text.

I am using the following but this displays the last maxlength for all the elements in question. My guess is that my last element is perhaps overwriting the others. 
Can someone tell me what I have to change here ?

```
var limit = '';
$('.limit').each(function() {
    limit = $(this).attr('maxlength');
    $(this).closest('tr').find($('.count').text(limit));
});
```

Many thanks in advance, Mike.

Comment: `$(this).closest('tr').find('.count').text(limit);`

Comment: `$('tr .count').text(function() { return $(this).closest('tr').find('.limit').attr('maxlength'); });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use:

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('.count').text(limit);
```

You don't need to convert `.count` to jQuery object inside `.find()` method. You also need to put `.text()` outside of `.find()`

Comment: Thanks a lot, that makes sense ! Will accept as soon as I can.